# dynamic list without javascript or realoading the page

Tags: html, css

I have a website which should be able to be executed without any javascript,

Now i want to use somehow Css and html to show a list with user input fields.
At the bottom of the List there should be a button for adding a new input field at the bottom of the list.

I know that css can show or hide html divs dynamically by setting display:none

My idea is to render a list with already 100 entries but only 10 of them are visible.
The user can "add" new elements by clicking the bottom at the bottom of the list.

the add button should be set as invisible and the next entry in the list and the next "add" button should be
displayed as visible.

so it is not really a dynamic list but a list with max 100 entries which should be enough for my use case.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please edit the question to include what have you tried and what was the specific problem that you encountered.

Comment: It's impossible. You need JS for that

Comment: please edit the question to include what have you tried and what was the specific problem that you want to fix

Comment: Something like this is why JavaScript was made

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using :checked in CSS3, here is an example

But this is not a good method, it would be better to use javascript. Otherwise, if you want to add new projects later, you will need to constantly change the code.

HTML:

```
<html>
  <div id="one">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
  <div>9</div>
  <div>10</div>
  </div>

  <input type = "checkbox" id = "show11">
  <label id = "add11" for = "show11" >add</label>
  
  <div id="eleven">
    <div>11</div>
    <div>12</div>
    <div>13</div>
    <div>14</div>
    <div>15</div>
    <div>16</div>
    <div>17</div>
    <div>18</div>
    <div>19</div>
    <div>20</div>
  </div>

    <input type = "checkbox" id = "show21">
    <label id = "add21" for = "show21" >add</label>  

</html>
```

CSS:

```
#eleven,#show11,#show21,#add21{
  display: none;
}

#show11:checked ~ #eleven {
  display: block;
}

#show11:checked ~ #add11 {
  display: none;
}

#show11:checked ~ #add21 {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: thank you so much. exactly what i was asking for